# Unable to disable touchpad in Dell Inspiron 13-5378

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, mouse, touchpad

I have an Dell Inspiron 13-5378 laptop. I'd like to disable its touchpad since I have an external mouse I can use. I Googled for "disable touchpad" and have tried the following so far:

- Going to *Device Manager*, selecting *Mice and other pointing devices*, and disabling both of the *HID-compliant mouse* entries I see

  - Disabling the first one appears to have no effect, as my touchscreen still works. Disabling the second one disables my mouse.
  - There is also a *PS/2 Compatible Mouse* entry, but I'm scared to touch it because I can only uninstall, not disable it, and I don't know what it does because I only have 1 mouse plugged in.
- Running `main.cpl` to get to *Mouse Properties*, going to *Hardware > Properties > Change settings...* yields the same issues: I can disable the first 2 "HID-compliant mouses" but can only uninstall the last one.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: The simple way to disable any touchpad is to uninstall and delete the device driver

Comment: Unless your mouse you have plugged in is a PS/2 mouse you should uninstall the ps/2 device

Comment: @Ramhound I just uninstalled the PS/2 driver and my touchpad still works...

Answer (score 0):

Wow-- after an hour so of digging around online and not getting anywhere (and uninstalling drivers), the problem turned out to be unexpectedly simple when I attempted it myself.

I have Windows 10, so I went to Settings > searched "mouse and touchpad". There, you'll find 2 toggle buttons: One for turning the touchpad off, one for turning the touchpad off when a mouse is plugged in.